# Minor scale with only 6th degree raised by a half step?

Tags: theory, guitar, chords, arpeggios

I've been playing some arpeggios on a guitar and eventually I set on three chords I've been repeating that sounded good to me. These chords were consisting of notes (from lowest to highest):

G F B♭ (no idea what the hell this is but it sounded good, G is the lowest note here)

F D A

E♭ C G

Together, they create a scale like that: C D E♭ F G A B♭, so it's almost C minor but with sixth degree raised half step. What is this scale? It's not harmonic minor which has the 7th degree raised, and it's not melodic minor which has both the 6th and 7th degree raised.

Is there any name for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A minor scale with the raised sixth degree is called the Dorian scale. It is actually a mode of the diatonic scale, which is the same as starting the major scale from the second degree, or starting minor from the fourth degree.

As a sidenote, G F B♭ could be considered a G minor 7th chord without the fifth. The fifth can often be omitted since it's not "essential" to determining the quality of a chord.

Comment: Ionian, Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, Mixolydian, Aeolian, Locrian.

Comment: Yeah I see it now. I forgot that it can be a modal scale, now I'm reminded of them and hopefully I will remember next time :) Thanks a lot for helping me! And yeah It'll be a G minor scale and as you said a G minor 7th chord without a fifth. Also thanks for editing my question. Case closed I guess.

Comment: I Don't Play Loud Music After Lunch.

Comment: Good answer, +1. 3 chords will be Gm7, Dm and Cm - all from some sort of G key.

Comment: I Don’t Play Like Mr Alan Limbrick.

Comment: And for the two Ls: remember the word “lilo” (ly-lo). You know, like an airbed...

Comment: I'd call the first one Bb5(13), and it's (thinks) VII-ii-i in the Dorian. Not quite a cadence :) but a nice way to end a phrase.

Comment: Scratch that, actually. Depending on how you look at it, all three could be seen as "add 6" (or "add 13") chords, and @michael-curtis is right that it's really Gm...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it only really makes sense to label a 13th chord if there's a 7th, since it's supposed to be a strong tension.

Answer (score 2):

> ...so it's almost C minor but with sixth degree raised half step

@awelotta's answer already points out the collection of tones is the Dorian mode.

But I think the more important thing that makes this *almost minor* - as in the *key* of `C` minor - is not the sixth degree but the seventh degree.

The general minor family is first defined by a mediant (3rd degree) of a minor third. The supertonic (2nd degree) and submediant (6th degree) are the other mode determining degrees. The minor modes include Dorian, Phrygian, Aeolian (skipping Locrian.) All three will share a subtonic (seventh degree a full step below tonic.) To get the music into a proper key of `C` minor the raised seventh degree is used.

You're playing...

```
G F B♭
F D A
E♭ C G
```

...that would be `Cm: v7 ii6 i6` in Roman numerals.

The important thing is the dominant chord - `v` - is minor. It uses a `B♭` instead of a `B` natural. That means the seventh degree is not raised for a *leading tone*. That is what really makes this *not a minor key*. It's modal instead. The sixth degree raised confirms Dorian mode. If the sixth was lowered, it would be Aeolian mode.

If the seventh was raised to `B` natural and the dominant chord then had a major third, it would then put the music into a proper minor key.

Comment: My impression of the chords in the OP is that they're actually "Gm: i7 v6 iv6".

Comment: Besides the OP listing tones starting on C and saying _almost C minor_, how would an Eb with a G tonic give a _raised_ sixth?

Comment: I'm not convinced the chords in the OP have a tonic of C. There's always at least a little ambiguity between C Dorian and G Aeolian, and I'm on the G Aeolian side.

Comment: So you're stating that a minor key is only a minor key when there's the leading note one semitone under the root? I believe that the minor part is caused by the minor third interval from the root, nothing else. Dorian, Phrygian , Aeolian, harmonic and melodic are all considered as minor due to that fact.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - with a G chord, a C chor and a D chord, all basic minr triads, i, iv and v, it's likely to be in key Gm, albeit using Bb notes, so it *could* be called C Dorian, but with i being G, it appears, would G Aeolian be a better label? Yes!

Comment: @Tim, right it would need the minor third mediant, I didn't think I needed to say that given the context, but I'll add an edit.

Comment: I still feel that having a 'raised' leadding note doesn't qualify a minor key. The fact that it needs to be called 'raised leading note' betrays that. The original 'non-raised leading note' is from the minor key!

Comment: It's probably better to say something like the `Bb` comes from the key signature, or Dorian/Aeolian mode depending on the key signature, and then using the raised seventh leading tone is indeed what makes the difference between the music being modal or minor _key._

Answer (score 2):

To me the chords look like: Gm7 - F6 - E♭6
and it could continue for example like this: B♭/D - Cm7 - B♭maj7 - Am7 - D7

Translated into three-note combinations like in your question:

- G - F - B♭ (Gm7)
- F - D - A (F6)
- E♭ - C - G (E♭6)
- D - B♭ - F (B♭/D)
- C - B♭ - E♭ (Cm7)
- B♭ - A - D (B♭maj7)
- A - G - C (Am7)
- D - F♯ - C (D7)

The fifth is omitted from all chords except B♭/D.

The key and scale would be G minor. Except D7 has an F♯ note but that's just normal in minor, and Am7 would have E, but that's normal as well and it's left out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment, but to me (probably because I'm not a guitarist) F D A and E♭ C G are inversions of Dm and Cm respectively, making your chord progression I7 - V - IV in the key of G (natural) minor.

Comment: Minors are usually written in lower case - i7, iv, v. This answer, to me, is a far more likely correct way to regard it all. +1.

Comment: There isn't a _key_ of natural minor. There isn't a dominant chord anywhere in the progression so we can at least say it isn't in a minor _key_. We would need to see more about the phrasing to really know what to call the tonic.